# LaTeX Error: File `label.sty' not found

Tags: labels

I'm beginer on LaTeX, I wrote a simple code on line, the one below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{label}
\begin{document}
mes premiers pas avec latex
\end{document}
```

But a message error appears: `` "LaTeX Error: File `label.sty' not found". `` 
How can I correct.
Thanks for help in advance.
Regards,

Comment: You probably want to `\usepackage[french]{babel}`.

Comment: because the article will be written in frensh

Comment: I see the point, and the package is called `babel` and not `label`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a typo (label instead of babel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your `\usepackage` line: the package is called `babel` and not `label`.